# How do you refresh a background image after the image has changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a project where the user can upload an image and the image will be stored in a MongoDB database. How can I update the background image of a div I have on the page every time a new image is uploaded without refreshing the page? I tried removing the background image and re-adding it, but it didn't seem to work:

```
function updateLogo() {
    console.log("update");
    $("#chain-logo").css("background-image", "none");
    $("#chain-logo").css("background-image", `url("/api/images/chain/${chainId}")`);
}
```

Here's the code that sends the image to the server and then calls updateLogo:

```
function uploadLogo() {
    let file = document.getElementById("logo-input").files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("logo", file);

    fetch(`/chain/${chainId}/upload/logo`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        updateLogo();
    });
}
```

HTML for the page:

```
<body>
    <div id="header-container"></div>
    <div id="administrator-message-banner">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="chain-logo-container">
        <input type="file" id="logo-input" accept=".png,.svg,.jpeg,.gif,.jpg,.txt" />
        <div id="chain-logo"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/chain.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS for div:

```
#chain-logo {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 260px;
    background-image: url("/public/images/chain-default.svg");
    background-size: 260px 200px;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to add a unique id to every uploaded image, so it's not cached when you try to change the background with the updated image.

Comment: I don't know if your image is dynamic, so try this: $("body #chain-logo").css(REST_OF_YOUR_CODE)

Comment: Rickard Elimää, each image gets a unique name when it's stored in the database, and then the server serves the most recent image to the api. I just need to find out how to get the image to refresh for the client. Rhadamez Gindri Hercilio, thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You could do a solution of something along the lines of `ImageElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);` in place of your `updateLogo()`. Of course, you would want to create a condition, using a higher scoped variable, that stops another upload until the last one is done. Either that, or if the image is uploaded to the Server and you have an actual URL and you might be using the same URL, add something to the end of a GET URL, like `'imagename.png?q='.uniqid('', true);` on the Server.

Comment: StackSlave, thanks for the help! I added a query string called requestNum to the URL and changed it each time I requested the image, and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to StackSlave for coming up with this idea!

I was able to fix my problem by changing my code to the following:

```
// updates logo
let requestNum = 0;
function updateLogo(chain) {
    fetch(`/api/chain/${chainId}/data`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            $("#chain-logo").css("background-image", `url("/api/images/chain/${chainId}?requestNum=${requestNum}")`);
        });
}
```

Each time I called the updateLogo function, I incremented the requestNum by 1 so that the url would be different every time.